# What is the probability that the next call come in $3$ minutes provided that in the past $2$ minutes there have been no calls?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

At a certain customer service line the waiting time for the next call follows exponential distribution with expected time $3$ minutes. What is the probability that the next call come in $3$ minutes provided that in the past $2$ minutes there have been no calls?

From the given datils we know $\lambda=\dfrac{1}{3}$ so the distribution

$P(X=x)=\frac{1}{3}e^-\frac{x}{3}$

We have to find $P(0<x<3/x>2)=\dfrac{P(2<x<3)}{p(x>2)}=\frac{\int_{2}^3 \frac{1}{3}e^-\frac{x}{3}\,dx}{\int_{2}^\infty \frac{1}{3}e^-\frac{x}{3}\,dx}$

but I am not sure this answer I think we have to find $P(2<x<3)$
Can someone help me to understand?

Comment: @AntoniParellada I checked it but it  is for $P(x>a+b/x>a)$

Comment: Say current time is 2 pm. Are you asking for the probability that a call will come before 2:03 given that no call has been received since 1:58?

Comment: I read the problem as (if it is 12:00 right now): What is the probability that the next call comes between 12:00 and 12:03, given that there was no call between 11:58 and 12:00.

Comment: It can be $P(X>3/X>2)=P(X>1)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen there are two answers but different?

Comment: @Daman exact question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator of the fraction is $P(0<x<3 \cap x>2)$. Thus you have to find the intersection of both. A number line helps to find it.

[image]

So the required probability is indeed $P(2<x<3)$. Thus the bounds are $2$ and $3$.

Comment: I don´t know the reason for the downvote. Please leave a comment.

Comment: Why is this downvorted I feel this is true but according to  the conditional probability it is not the case

Comment: Can you please tell me why the conditional probability is wrong?

Comment: @jlammy I gave an answer only for the numerator.

Comment: @callculus cool understood

Comment: @callculus what is you denominator

Comment: @noname Obviously $P(x>2)$

Comment: So my attempt apparently correct

Comment: In my opinion yes.

Answer (score 2):

From the way you phrased the question, I'm assuming that if the current time is 2pm, you are asking for the probability that a call will come before 2:03 given that no call has been received since 1:58.

The key here is that the exponential distribution is *memoryless*, i.e.
$$\mathbb P(X>a+b\mid X\geq b)=\mathbb P(X>a).$$
So in this case, $$\mathbb P(X>3+2\mid X\geq2)=\mathbb P(X>3)=e^{-\frac{1}{3}\times3}=e^{-1}.$$
So the probability that a customer will arrive in the next three minutes is $1-e^{-1}$. The memoryless property means that the fact we haven't received a call in the past two minutes doesn't affect the probability.

---

If instead the interpretation is that the current time is 2pm, no call has been received since 1:58, what is the probability a call will come before 2:01, then the memoryless property implies that the answer is $\mathbb P(X\leq1)=1-e^{-1/3}$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be valid if it was stated as "next 3 minutes"?

Comment: @Daman my interpretation of "next call come in 3 minutes" is that the next call would arrive within three minutes of the present moment. As I say in my answer though, the memoryless property applies whichever way you look at it.

Comment: your answers is difference from callculas's answer

Comment: @noname callculus' interpretation corresponds to my second interpretation. In any case, you were correct in your idea that you need to divide by $\mathbb P(X\geq 2)$

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer